# Send data from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I tried to send a list from my servlet to a jsp page. This is the servlet code:

```
Query q = new Query("post").addSort("time", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

QueryResultList<Entity> results = pq.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);
for (Entity entity : results) {
    System.out.println(entity.getProperty ("content"));
    System.out.println(entity.getProperty ("time"));
}
req.setAttribute("postList",results);
req.getRequestDispatcher("/tublr.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

The jsp code:

```
<%
    QueryResultList<Entity> result = request.getAttribute("postList");
    for (Entity entity : results) {           
        <b> IT WORRRKKKK !!! </b> <br>
    }
%>
```

But I get an error

**EDIT :** I added

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ page import="java.util.List,com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.SortDirection,com.google.appengine.api.datastore.*" %>
```

And now i get a new error

> An error occurred at line: 37 in the jsp file: /tublr.jsp Type
>   mismatch: cannot convert from Object to QueryResultList .....
>   Caused by:
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

I m do it for the school and we have to di it like this now , we have to use java in the jsp page.

Comment: As others have said, do not embed Java code in your JSPs. Use JSTL instead.

Comment: As I mentioned on your last post....JSTL foreach.....

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to add `import` statements at top of the JSP.

Example:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
```

2) It is **NOT** good practice to have Java code directly embedded in JSP

Read more here on [SO Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do any coding on JSP page. There is a [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) library for this kind of stuff, and to iterate and display stuff you should use `forEach` tag:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
```

and for loop

```
<x:forEach select="${postList}" var="item">
    ... code
</x:forEach>
```

Comment: I think this is very advanced for me, I m doing it for the school

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported `QueryResultList` in your jsp?

Comment: This should be a comment ..not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You forgot <% %> for the html code

```
<%
   QueryResultList<Entity> result = request.getAttribute("postList");

   for (Entity entity : results) {           

          %> <b> IT WORRRKKKK !!! </b> <br><%

   }

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast list obtained from `request.getAttribute("postList")` to `QueryResultList`.

```
<%
    QueryResultList<Entity> result =(QueryResultList)request.getAttribute("postList");
    for (Entity entity : result) {           
       // Your code goes here  You can use <%= %> to print values. 
       // <b> IT WORRRKKKK !!! </b> <br>

    }
%>
```

For more about [expression](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-expression-tag)