# Send complex data type from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, formatting

[Last Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350461/send-data-from-servlet-to-jsp?noredirect=1#comment25175549_17350461)

I'm tring to send a QueryResultList from a servlet to a jsp page. I wrote this code

```
QueryResultList<Entity> results = pq.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);
System.out.println("-------------------");

for (Entity entity : results) {             
    System.out.println(entity.getProperty ("content"));
    System.out.println(entity.getProperty ("time"));
}

req.setAttribute("postList",results);
req.getRequestDispatcher("/tublr.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

and the jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List,com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.SortDirection,com.google.appengine.api.datastore.*" %>

<%
    QueryResultList<Entity> result = request.getAttribute("postList");
    for (Entity entity : results) {           
%>  
<b> IT WORRRKKKK !!! </b> <br> 
<%
    }
%>
```

But i get an error  An error occurred at line: 37 in the jsp file:

> /tublr.jsp Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to
>   QueryResultList 34:   .... Caused by:
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

I'm doing it for the school so I have to do it in this way ( using java code in the jsp page )

**EDIT :** I still have this error , i don't understand, it work fine in the Servlet ...

```
An error occurred at line: 40 in the jsp file: /tublr.jsp
results cannot be resolved
37:        QueryResultList<Entity> result = (QueryResultList<Entity>)request.getAttribute("postList");
38: 
39:            
40:            for (Entity entity : results) {           
41:                  
42:                   %>  <b> IT WORRRKKKK !!! </b> <br> <%
43:
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast `request.getAttribute("postList");` to `QueryResultList<Entity>`

Change

```
<%
    QueryResultList<Entity> result = request.getAttribute("postList");
```

to

```
<%
    QueryResultList<Entity> result = (QueryResultList<Entity>)request.getAttribute("postList");
```

if the request attribute is a `QueryResultList<Entity>`. Also, you should review basic java. It doesn't seem like you understand the exception you got.

Comment: I understand but i thought request.getAttribute is already an QueryResult List<Entity>. I still have an error in the line for (Entity entity : results) {

Comment: @user2528061 The actual object is of that type. But the method has a return type of `Object`, so you need to cast it to your type or the compiler will complain. Add your new error as an edit to your question.

Comment: @user2528061 `results` does not exist in what you showed. Did you mean `result`? Does `QueryResultList` implement `Iterable`?

Comment: Ohhh it was the "s" It was the mistake, but now I have a NullPointerException :/

Comment: @user2528061 That means that `request.getAttribute()` returned `null`. That means that you didn't set it properly.

Comment: I just used this code   req.setAttribute("postList",results);
    
   
     req.getRequestDispatcher("/tublr.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    Shall I put it in the session too ?

Comment: @user2528061 With what you've shown, it shouldn't be happening. Double check and update your question if you changed something.

Answer (score 0):

```
QueryResultList<Entity> result = (QueryResultList<Entity>) request.getAttribute("postList");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 QueryResultList<Entity> result = request.getAttribute("postList");
```

to this and see :

```
 QueryResultList<Entity> result = (QueryResultList<Entity>)request.getAttribute("postList");
```

Make sure the postList you are returning is a list of type Entity

Answer (score -1):

Try not to use scriptlets inside JSP, because it makes very difficult for others to maintain. Instead, you can use JSTL in the JSP.